# Shell TabBar rounded corners override default background color (View) behind

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm applying rounded corner on a Shell TabBar like in [Xamarin Forms Shell TabBar Rounded Corner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65783667).

My question: is it possible to put the view (background color) behind instead of above (default black color)?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the question you linked is about setting round corners ?

Comment: oops no, mistake. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `BackgroundColor` of the Parent to either the current `ContentPage` `BackgroundColor` or to it `Content` (probably a Layout) `BackgroundColor`.

```
    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            var currentContentPage = (Shell.Current.CurrentPage as ContentPage);
            if (currentContentPage == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (currentContentPage.Content != null && currentContentPage.Content.BackgroundColor != Color.Transparent)
            {
                (bottomView.Parent as LinearLayout)?.SetBackgroundColor(currentContentPage.Content.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            }
            else
            {
                (bottomView.Parent as LinearLayout)?.SetBackgroundColor(currentContentPage.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            }

            bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.bottombackground);
        }
```

#### Note

Since it is a follow-up question I just put the relevant code specific for this question, the full code could be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784730

Answer (score 0):

You can define the drawable background as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#f00" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In addition, you can set the Elevation property to 0 in order to prevent the shadow:

```
bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.bottombackground);
bottomView.Elevation = 0;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `<solid android:color="#ffffff"` is hard-coded, so if he set the BackgroundColor of one of his ContentPage, or set a StackLayout as the Content and give it a  BackgroundColor you will find yourself in the same issue of the question.

Comment: It's true, it's hardcoded, but it's a valid solution when you have the same background color in your views. I'm trying to use the same drawable background file.

Comment: Agree it's a valid solution I have just pointed out that scenario because I have myself hard-coded the color initially before figuring out this could be inconvenient in that scanario.