# Shell flyout with round corners

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.shell

Trying to customize the Shell flyout by setting it corner radius in order to have a flyout with round corners. Since there is no property related to Shell flyout corner radius, is there a way to achieve that with a custom renderer?

Comment: I never try it, but did you try to set the flyout background color to Transparent and then create a view inside with PancakeView ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion no I didn't, because the flyout content is auto generated (the default) based on whatever is your Appshell hiearchy. I am not setting `Shell.FlyoutContent`

Comment: @FabriBertani you may convert your comment suggestion into an answer for future readers, I tried it and it is working :). In the case where `FlyoutContent` or `FlyoutContentTemplate` is being set instead of the auto generated one, it's a much better approach than a custom renderer.

Comment: Oh cool, also I'll assume that works on both platforms ;-D

Comment: @FabriBertani Sure since it is implemented in shared code unless a bug in XF itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't see a way to do it in the shared code when using the auto generated flyout content based on AppShell hierarchy (if you are overriding it skip to the **Edit** section), here is a solution to get it done using a custom renderer for Android:

1. In your Android project, in `Resources\drawable`, add:

**flyoutbackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

2. In your Android project, implement a `ShellRenderer` for your AppShell:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App1.AppShell), typeof(AppShellRenderer))]
namespace App1.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class AppShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public AppShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellFlyoutContentRenderer CreateShellFlyoutContentRenderer()
        {
            var flyoutContentRenderer = base.CreateShellFlyoutContentRenderer();
            var flyoutbackground = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(Platform.CurrentActivity, Resource.Drawable.flyoutbackground);

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt > Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                flyoutbackground.SetColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(
                    Shell.Current.FlyoutBackgroundColor.ToAndroid(), BlendMode.Color));
                flyoutContentRenderer.AndroidView.SetBackground(flyoutbackground);
            }
            else
            {
                flyoutbackground.SetColorFilter(Shell.Current.FlyoutBackgroundColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Src);
                flyoutContentRenderer.AndroidView.SetBackgroundDrawable(flyoutbackground);
            }
            return flyoutContentRenderer;
        }
}
```

#### Render result

[image]

#### Limitation

- The corner radius is hard-coded.
- Seems to be not working for Android API <= 26, please feel free to fix/improve the code on this answer.

#### Note

A similar analogy could be implemented for iOS, here is an answer that might help [Xamarin Forms Shell TabBar Rounded Corner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784730).

Related question: [Shell TabBar rounded corners with view behind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67071250/)

#### Edit

If you are overriding the flyout content using `Shell.FlyoutContent` or `FlyoutContentTemplate` instead of the auto generated content based on AppShell hierarchy, then check [@FabriBertani comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130192/shell-flyout-with-round-corners/67130193#comment118659548_67130192) as you don't require a custom renderer to achieve that.