# Xamarin Shell android customize with xml markup

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've defined custom bottomview to make custom tabbar shell in android project.
To make this, I created a new render and a new xml file to define the graphics.
But there is a problem, I have `margin` but the background under the bottom view is black and I don't know how I can edit this color.

This is my code:

```
public class MyShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {            
        bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.bottomBack);                                  

        if (bottomView.LayoutParameters is LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams)
        {
            layoutParams.SetMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
            bottomView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my xml of shell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="#fff555" />
  
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
     android:topRightRadius="15dp"
           android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
  />
  <padding android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"/>
  
</shape>
```

The result appears with background of view gray, shell with yellow color and Black in background but for the last one I don't know how I can edit (make gray as rest of view).

[Screen about background tab bar is black and not gray as rest of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAWI4.png)

How can I specify the tab bar background (out of margin)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell TabBar rounded corners override default background color (View) behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071250/shell-tabbar-rounded-corners-override-default-background-color-view-behind)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get Parent of bottomView,then set its background color to gray.

```
 public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
       
        bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.bottombackground);
        Android.Views.View view = (Android.Views.View)bottomView.Parent;
        view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
        if (bottomView.LayoutParameters is LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams)
        {
            layoutParams.SetMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
            bottomView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        }
    }
```