# How can I make custom tabbed page?(Rounded frame on the bottom)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, customization

How can I make custom tabbed page?
Sorry for a stupid question,but please help.Maybe someone now how to make custom tabbed page like this
I don't know how to make this rounded frame at the bottom to customize the tabbed page

[image]

Comment: Make ur parent layout grid with no row and no column and put frame at last with VerticalOptions="End"

Comment: I need Tabbed Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit) available via NuGet. There you have [examples](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/TabView/CustomTabsPage.xaml), which might help with getting what you want.
This is what I quickly got by looking at their example:

[image]

Use `TabStripBackgroundView` to get rounded frame, like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestTabbedCustom.MainPage"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit">

    <Grid>
        <xct:TabView
                TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
                TabStripHeight="60"
                TabIndicatorColor="Yellow"
                TabContentBackgroundColor="Yellow"
                IsTabTransitionEnabled ="True">
                <xct:TabView.TabStripBackgroundView>
                <BoxView
                        Color="Blue"
                        CornerRadius="36, 36, 0, 0"/>
                 </xct:TabView.TabStripBackgroundView>
            
            <xct:TabViewItem
                    Icon="icon.png"
                    Text="Tab 1"
                    TextColor="White"
                    TextColorSelected="Yellow"
                    FontSize="12">
                <Grid 
                        BackgroundColor="Gray">
                    <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Text="TabContent1" />
                </Grid>
            </xct:TabViewItem>

            <xct:TabViewItem
                    Icon="icon.png"
                    Text="Tab 2"
                    TextColor="White"
                    TextColorSelected="Yellow"
                    FontSize="12">
                <Grid>
                    <Label    
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Text="TabContent2" />
                </Grid>
            </xct:TabViewItem>
        </xct:TabView>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android:**

Add the `shape_indicator_radius.xml` in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"  >
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"/>
  <solid
       android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Set background in the Tabbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/shape_indicator_radius">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

In MainActivity, set the `TabLayoutResource` in OnCreate method.

```
 TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
```

**iOS:**

You could do this with custom renderer.

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage),typeof(MyCustomRenderer))]
namespace App4.iOS
{
    class MyCustomRenderer: TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            this.TabBar.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            this.TabBar.Translucent = true;
            
            this.TabBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
            this.TabBar.Layer.CornerRadius = 50;
            this.TabBar.Layer.MaskedCorners = 
            CoreAnimation.CACornerMask.MaxXMinYCorner | 
            CoreAnimation.CACornerMask.MinXMinYCorner;
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: It does not work if I want to do bottom tabbar

Comment: On iOS, the list of tabs appears at the bottom of the screen. On Android, the list of tabs appears at the top of the screen. But if we move the tabs to the bottom of the screen on Android, some seetings does not work. For solution, you could use Shell tabs instead. Check the link below about how to use the shell renderer to set the corner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783667/xamarin-forms-shell-tabbar-rounded-corner