# Customize TopBar on Maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-7.0

this task is ridicolous but I can't find any info in internet. So please show mercy show mercy to me.

I want to customize the top bar of my MAUI application ([The part in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIDDW.png)). How I can do that?

Thank you for your support

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-7.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom renderer like Xamarin.Forms for Shell (No need to add `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Shell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]` ). If you want to create a custom tabbar. Nomally, for android, you need to override `CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker` . For iOS, you need to override `CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker` method.

Then, register your custom renderer for shell in the .MauiProgram.cs

```
builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
      .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
      {
           ....
      }).ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => { 
           
                        #if ANDROID
                            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer));
                        #elif iOS
                             handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(MyiOSCustomShellRenderer));
               
                        #endif
            });
```

You can refer to this article [Xamarin Forms Shell TabBar Rounded Corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783667/xamarin-forms-shell-tabbar-rounded-corner) to customize the top bar by using the shellrender.